# MYSQL query to find most popular entry

Tags: mysql

My table looks like:

```
hook_bait  | brand    | flavour
----------------------------------
corn       |          |
bread      |          |
boily      | variable | variable
```

I need to run a mysql query that will give me the name of the most popular hook_bait, and if a boily - what brand and flavour the most popular boily is.

I am not sure where to start

Comment: How do you count popularity?

Comment: You need a scorint mechanism for popularity. How is it measured?

Comment: There is nothing in that table that can tell you about popularity, where are the numbers?

Comment: I could be going about this all wrong - I need to be able to find out what has been entered the most.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the most popular hook_bait by query like this:

```
SELECT 
  hook_bait, 
  COUNT(hook_bait) AS popularity
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY hook_bait
ORDER BY popularity DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Complete example query:

```
SELECT 
  hook_bait, 
  IF(hook_bait = 'boily', (SELECT brand FROM sample_table t2 WHERE t2.hook_bait = t1.hook_bait GROUP BY brand ORDER BY COUNT(brand) DESC LIMIT 1), '-') AS brand,
  IF(hook_bait = 'boily', (SELECT flavour FROM sample_table t2 WHERE t2.hook_bait = t1.hook_bait GROUP BY flavour ORDER BY COUNT(flavour) DESC LIMIT 1), '-') AS flavour
FROM sample_table t1
GROUP BY hook_bait
ORDER BY COUNT(hook_bait) DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: 23 seconds after the op commented, nice! :D

Comment: that was rapid - appreciate your help

Comment: Nice one buddy, I hope this helps someone else also!